# Uploaded image file does not any preview in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, postman, azure-ad-msal

I am sending a POST(PUT) request to upload an image to Sharepoint private group folder. I am using MS Graph API & Azure AD Authentications. When I am testing the link with a Postman It returns Status 201 created success response. Even though the file was uploaded successfully, then clicking on the file in Sharepoint does not have any content to preview only the image name is displayed.

my request is below.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{drive-id}}/items/{{item-id}}:/fruit.jpg:/content
```

Content-Type: application/json

It is empty as like as below images.

```
Sharepoint Content
```

[image: Sharepoint content]

```
Empty preview of the image
```

[image: Empty Preview of the image]

Can anyone help me with this to find out what I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to several common problems.

1. Incorrect file path
2. File names misspelled
3. Wrong file extension
4. Transfer problems

Referring above reasons I've been able to figure out where is my problem and I'm done with it.

I've my request path to something like below.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{siteId}}/drive/items/{{itemId}}:/{{fileName}}:/content](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7B%7BsiteId%7D%7D/drive/items/%7B%7BitemId%7D%7D:/%7B%7BfileName%7D%7D:/content)

This link properly adds files to my SharePoint private group folder in shared documents.

Note: {{siteId}}, {{itemId}} & {{fileName}} are variables.